# symfony2: saving form data in a single step

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.6

my form got 4 fields after validation when i look for the insert procedure if found i have to do the following which works fine too

```
if($form->isValid()){
           $data = $form->getData();
           $entity->setName($data->getName());
           $entity->setEmail($data->getEmail());
           $entity->setStatus($data->getStatus());
           $entity->setSubscribedon($data->getSubscribedon());
           $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
           $em->persist($entity);
           $em->flush();
           $session->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Subscriber added successfully');
           return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_subscribers'));        
        }
```

but do we got any other way like mass assign data to insert ? like in Yii we can assign entire form fields with out setting individual form data , suppose if my form got 15 fields do i have to call set method for each of them ? is there any other way of doing it ?

thank you

Comment: yes pass your entity's new object in create form builder method and after all validations just persist form object

Comment: @ M Khalid Junaid thanks its worked

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass entity object when you create form, then after form validation just persist that entity

```
$entity = new Entity();
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$form = $this->createForm(new FormType(), $entity);
$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();
     return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_subscribers'));
}
```